# How to serialize sql data without the column names?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, sql-server-2012

I am Serializing data from SQL database to JSON, how can I serialize just the values without the string name OR  a function to trim the serialized JSON before Deserializing.

I read about ScriptIgnoreAttribute but didn't see how to relate it with what I want to do

Original JSON

```
​[
    {
        "CODE": "AF",
        "TOTALVALUE": "$23,554,857.27"
    },
    {
        "CODE": "AS",
        "TOTALVALUE": "$38,379,964.65"
    },
    {
        "CODE": "SG",
        "TOTALVALUE": "$24,134,283.47"
    }
]
```

Desired JSON

```
​[
    {
        "AF": "$23,554,857.27"
    },
    {
        "AS": "$38,379,964.65"
    },
    {
        "SG": "$24,134,283.47"
    }
]
```

SQL View structure

[image]

My SQL query to return the data

```
SELECT [CODE],[TOTALVALUE] FROM [dbo].[vw_BuyersByCountryValue]
enter code here
```

Code for Serializing in ASP.NET

```
[WebMethod]
    public void GetBuyersByCountryValue()
    {

        using (PMMCEntities ctx = new PMMCEntities())
        {
            ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            var qry = ctx.vw_BuyersByCountryValue.ToList();

            var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string strResponse = js.Serialize(qry);
            Context.Response.Clear();
            Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", strResponse.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            Context.Response.Flush();
            Context.Response.Write(strResponse);
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add code, please. See: [mcve].

Comment: the title of this post includes the word 'ignore'.  if that is not your intention i would suggest correcting that to attract better answers

Comment: my 2c worth of advice here - JavaScriptSerializer has no way to rename a property for serialization outside of writing a custom JavaScriptConverter. This serializer is quite bare-bones; the only serialization attribute it supports is ScriptIgnore to suppress serialization of a property.  Try another library to get what you want.

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: Please share the SQL script used to get the data. It can be transformed before the conversion to JSON.

Comment: `code` 
SELECT [CODE],[TOTALVALUE] FROM [dbo].[vw_BuyersByCountryValue]

Comment: Please edit the question add the SQL statement and the JavaScriptSerializer code(to meet the minimal code requirements).  and the tag for the SQL server(I am assuming MSSQL). I have to do some research on `AS`, `PIVOT` and `CUBE`. It has been too many years.

Comment: You can use a PIVOT as mentioned by @Strom, if you know the CODE value ahead of time (i.e. it is fixed), if not, or if there are numerous different CODE values you can create a dynamic sql statement to use the CODE value as the column header name.

Comment: @peeyushsingh, PIVOT it is(I have the code setup in answer). I am awaiting code for the object population code from the OP, so I can provide a dynamic split and rejoin in C#(to minimize the number of DB accesses required: 1 long row vs many 2 column requests.)

Comment: The OP needs to mention the DB also, there are probably functions in DB to convert JSON, alternately it should be easy enough to do in C#

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple

```
// data from the query 
// SELECT CODE, TOTALVALUE FROM vw_BuyersByCountryValue
var sqldata = new [] 
{ 
    new { Code = "AF", TotalValue = "$23,554,857.27" },  
    new { Code = "AS", TotalValue = "$38,379,964.65" },  
    new { Code = "SG", TotalValue = "$24,134,283.47" },  
};

var mappeddata = sqldata.Select( r => 
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    dict[r.Code] = r.TotalValue;
    return dict;
});

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mappeddata,Formatting.Indented);
```

content of `json`

```
[
  {
    "AF": "$23,554,857.27"
  },
  {
    "AS": "$38,379,964.65"
  },
  {
    "SG": "$24,134,283.47"
  }
]
```

[.net fiddle sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7sHmud)

---

You can even populate it as

```
{
  "AF": "$23,554,857.27",
  "AS": "$38,379,964.65",
  "SG": "$24,134,283.47"
}
```

with

```
var sqldata = new [] 
{ 
    new { Code = "AF", TotalValue = "$23,554,857.27" },  
    new { Code = "AS", TotalValue = "$38,379,964.65" },  
    new { Code = "SG", TotalValue = "$24,134,283.47" },  
};

var mappeddata = sqldata.ToDictionary(r => r.Code, r => r.TotalValue);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mappeddata,Formatting.Indented);
```

[.net fiddle sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4DeyUV)

---

**Update**

```
[WebMethod]
public void GetBuyersByCountryValue()
{
    using (PMMCEntities ctx = new PMMCEntities())
    {
        ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var qry = ctx.vw_BuyersByCountryValue.ToList();

        var mapped = qry.Select r => 
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
            dict[r.CODE] = r.TOTALVALUE;
            return dict;
        });

        string strResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mapped);

        Context.Response.Clear();
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", strResponse.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        Context.Response.Flush();
        Context.Response.Write(strResponse);
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
}
```

You need the NuGet package **Newtonsoft.Json**

Comment: Thanks Sir Rufo, but am loading the data directly from the database not manually creating the data as you have shared. Thanks

Comment: Sorry that I did not setup a SQL Server with all your data. Do you really have problems to read data row by row from the query and fill it in a dictionary?

Comment: Yes Sir Rufo, am having issues since the result from the sql is returned as a list

Comment: When you have a list, then you can iterate. When you can iterate you can fill the dict

Comment: @MichaelMarmah I modified your code how it should be - but I am not sure about the properties CODE and TOTALVALUE and I had to guess because you did not post the class definition.